# compare two files

Tags: bash, awk, compare

I have two files which are different row :

file 1:

```
31.32   29.15   46.77   106.40  11370
25.81   40.82   25.67   30.08   16365
27.11   42.32   14.48   50.04   18310.7
26.48   42.34   12.65   62.78   19607.5
24.48   46.00   17.16   11.86   22087.2
26.75   43.91   29.65   55.81   24032.7
30.91   34.85   15.25   50.93   26703
25.24   41.62   16.54   51.57   38032.9
23.48   41.97   17.33   50.88   48981.2
24.16   39.34   16.99   50.86   77513.4
22.90   41.59   19.76   50.31   135803
19.98   43.52   20.58   45.65   747049
19.96   43.64   20.43   45.37   809913
19.93   43.75   20.41   45.33   863931
```

and file 2:

```
12.4   -32.1    39.1    -44.9   135497.688
8.6    -38.6    39.3    -44.8   48981.191
1.0    -45.0    0.0     -54.0   45928.445
13.9   -70.1    39.4    -44.8   26702.982
```

I would like to compare these two files and the output :

file 3

```
13.9  -70.1   30.91  34.85   39.4   -44.8   15.25   50.93   26702.982
8.6   -38.6   23.48  41.97   39.3   -44.8   17.33   50.88   48981.191
```

The problem is  the respective columns value in the two files are not exactly matched. But It will be fine if they match within certain error bounds (e.g., +/- 1).

---

Annotating where values in file 3 come from, using F/R/C for File/Row/Column:

```
13.9  -70.1   30.91  34.85   39.4   -44.8   15.25   50.93   26702.982
2/4/1 2/4/2   1/7/1  1/7/2   2/4/3  2/4/4   1/7/3   1/7/4   2/4/5

8.6   -38.6   23.48  41.97   39.3   -44.8   17.33   50.88   48981.191
2/2/1 2/2/2   1/9/1  1/9/2   2/2/3  2/2/4   1/9/3   1/9/4   2/2/5
```

But:

- Why are there no entries for the other lines in File 2?
- Why are there no entries for the other lines in File 1?
- How are the values in File 1 Row 7 related to the values in File 2 Row 4?
- How are the values in File 1 Row 9 related to the values in File 2 Row 2?
- Why is Column 5 of File 1 not in the output?
- Is File 1 Column 5 joined with Column 5 of File 2, with a tolerance of ±1?

Comment: Could you please post a more readable, minimal example that exhibits the essence of your question?

Comment: What do these values represent, and what in File #1 is suppose to make File #2?

Comment: I want the output file as file #3, the file is generated from comparable column #5 at  file #1 and file #2 , but the problem is the respective columns value in the two files are not exactly matched. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: What's the math to generate file#3 after comparing file#1 and #2? o_O

Comment: I would like to compare file #1 and file #2 and generate file # 3 with awk or maybe bash script, have someone idea ?

Comment: Which column in file #1 matches file #2; or which columns?

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
(LC_ALL=C; join -1 5 -2 5 \
    <(<file1 awk '{printf "%s %s %s %s %d\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,int($5+0.5);}' | sort -nk5)\
    <(<file2 awk '{printf "%s %s %s %s %d\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,int($5+0.5);}' | sort -nk5)
) | awk '{print $2, $3, $6, $7, $4, $5, $8, $9, $1}'
```

will produce for your input this:

```
13.9 -70.1 30.91 34.85 39.4 -44.8 15.25 50.93 26703
8.6 -38.6 23.48 41.97 39.3 -44.8 17.33 50.88 48981
```

The last column is rounded.

more compact form:

```
cmd() {
    awk '{printf "%s %s %s %s %d\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,int($5+0.5);}' | sort -nk5
}
(LC_ALL=C; join -1 5 -2 5 <(<file1 cmd) <(<file2 cmd)) |\
awk '{print $2, $3, $6, $7, $4, $5, $8, $9, $1}'
```

Comment: Thank @jm666, your script is working too, it is impressive a shell script

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '
    function close_enough(v1, v2, delta) {
        delta = v1 - v2
        return (-1 <= delta && delta <= 1)
    }
    NR == FNR {
        key[$NF] = $0
        next
    }
    {
        for (val in key) {
            if (close_enough($NF,val)) {
                split(key[val], arr)
                print arr[1], arr[2], $1, $2, arr[3], arr[4], $3, $4, val
            }
        }
    }
' file2 file1 | column -t > file3
```

Comment: +1. Impressive! :). I wrote a program which is just double the size of your program.

Comment: At first I thought your solution would not work.  Then I ran it and saw it got the correct result.  Then I thought you were lucky.  Then I studied it more and have concluded that it is absolutely brilliant!

Comment: @grok12, I'd upvote your comment but that seems a bit self-serving.

Comment: Actually I had forgotten to upvote your answer until just now.

Answer (score 0):

Only with awk.

```
awk '
NR==FNR {a[int($5+0.5)] = $0; next}
a[int($5+0.5)] {$0 = a[int($5+0.5)] " " $0; print $6,$7,$1,$2,$8,$9,$10}' file1 file2
```

If you need it to be sorted, pipe the output into `sort`